# TRAMP hangs after timeout on trying to connect

Tags: tramp, ssh

After I type `C-x /remote.server.com TAB /`, the prompt changes to spinning bar and nothing more happens. After around a minute of waiting I get the same prompt I was entering, i.e. `/remote.server.com:`. There’s also a buffer `*tramp/scp remote.server.com` opened, but it’s empty. In the Messages buffer I can see

```
Tramp: Opening connection for remote.server.com using scp...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none remote.server.com'
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Timeout reached, see buffer `*tramp/scp remote.server.com*' for details
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for remote.server.com using scp...failed
```

Autocompletion for `ssh remote.server.com:/` works in a regular terminal, and shows in a couple of seconds. The server in question uses options from `~/.ssh/config`, such as User, Port, HostName, IdentityFile to connect.

---

Debug output: http://sprunge.us/MFig

Debug output after changing remote PS1 to ‘#’: http://sprunge.us/DLcH

Comment: Same here. I read all the comments to the one answer there is currently and must say it is the same here. No output even with verbose 10 for tramp, normal connect possible in the shell without problems. But one more thing: while I see the spinning wheel, I do not see an ssh process on my machine. Yet, after I waited for a timeout, the message window contains: byte-code: [[Regexp `\(^[^#$%>
]*[#$%>] *\|[a-zA-Z/~:]+[])}] ?
\)\'' not found in 60 secs]]. The last part of the regex is what I added to match the target host and it has worked in the past like this.

Answer (score 3):

Pls set `(setq tramp-verbose 10)` and rerun the test. There will be a debug buffer, which you shall show us.

In case you don't want to show it publicly, send it to me via email.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve added the link with debug output to my post.

Comment: There's no output at all. Strange. Pls open a local shell, and call there `ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none remote.server.com` (replacing the real server name). What happens?

Comment: It logins and shows the prompt: `remote.server.com ~ #`

Comment: This shall be visible in the debug buffer. Anyway, your prompt is not helpful for Tramp. Could you disable prompt setting at all on your remote server, temporarily? Setting `$PS1` to `#` or something like this.

Comment: I’ve added `PS1='#'` to the end of /etc/bash/bashrc on the remote.server.com. The output added to the post.

Comment: Sorry, but there's still absolutely no output from the last command. I cannot say anything else without debugging. Just one question: how did you start Emacs? Please start it as `emacs -Q`, without any init file, and try to connect the remote server.

Comment: Just one question: how did you start Emacs? — as `emacs --daemon`. — Please start it as `emacs -Q`, without any init file, and try to connect the remote server. — That way I see the same behaviour, i.e. not connecting, but what I don’t see is any buffers tramp should have open. So no output at all. Not even to the terminal.

Comment: I fear a cannot do anymore here on stackexchange. You could write a Tramp error, and I will continue to handle this problem via the Tramp ML. But as it looks now I would need to debug it on your machine. I'm not sure whether you want this.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was due to rogue declaration of paths in my bash profile `.bashrc`:

```
GOROOT=/Users/jay/work 
PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

I removed those lines from `.bashrc` and the problem resolved.

Comment: The only thing added to my PATH is ~/bin. Running emacs with alternated environment, where it isn’t present in the PATH, did nothing.